# How to make Django views require a user login?

Tags: html, django, security, authentication, django-forms

I have a Django project with a login screen; when I enter my username and password I get directed to the home page. This works fine! But nothing is secure, I can just go to the view at /allstudyplans without logging in and see all the information there. My Question is how do I make it so it's not possible to go /allstudyplans without logging in first?

Form

```
User = get_user_model()


class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
username = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'autofocus': '',
        'placeholder': 'Användarnamn',
    }
), )

password = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.PasswordInput(
    attrs={
        'class': 'form-control mt-1',
        'placeholder': 'Lösenord',
    }
), )

# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    username = cleaned_data.get('username')
    password = cleaned_data.get('password')

    if username and password:
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if not user:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                'Oh! I can\'t find that user - create user first!')
        elif not user.check_password(password):
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                'Oh! That password is incorrect - try again!')
        elif not user.is_active:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                'Oh! That user is not active in the database!')
```

Views

```
def home(request):
next = (request.GET.get('next'))
form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
    password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    login(request, user)
    if next:
        return redirect(next)
    return redirect('/')

context = {
    'form': form,
}
  return render(request, "utility-login.html", context)

def Assignments(request):
  return render(request, 'nav-side-team.html')

def DetailAssignment(request):
obj = Assignment.objects.all()
context = {
    'object': obj
}
  return render(request, 'nav-side-project.html', context)

def studyplans(request):
  return render(request, 'allStudyplans.html')

def detailStudyplan(request):
  return render(request, 'detailStudyplan.html')
```

Also a Home View in the normal project file (not the app)

```
@login_required
def homee(request):
    return render(request, "allstudyplans.html", {})
```

Urls in the project:

```
 urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path('account/', include('accounts.urls')),
  path('', include('accounts.urls'))
 ]
```

Urls in the app:

```
 urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.studyplans),
   path('login', views.home),
   path('nav-side-team.html', views.Assignments),
   path('nav-side-project.html', views.DetailAssignment),
   path('allstudyplans.html', views.studyplans),
   path('detailStudyplan.html', views.detailStudyplan),
 ]
```

Tried this:

```
@login_required
def Assignments(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('%s?next=%s' % ('utility-login.html', request.path))
    return render(request, 'nav-side-team.html')
```

Comment: [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users) explains all your need. You're already using the `@login_required` decorator in one of your views, so that should word.

Comment: I tried putting the @login_required on all views but that didn't work, should I do the if user is authenticated then return the view?

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? That's not possible. If the user isn't logged in, he/she will be redirected to the login page.

Comment: Can you add a log and check that the end-point you're invoking is actually executing the correct view ? As I see that your same views are hooked to multiple endpoints

Comment: Have you defined `LOGIN_URL`?

Comment: like this: @login_required
def Assignments(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL, request.path))
    return render(request, 'nav-side-team.html')

Comment: LOGIN_URL is set to 'utility-login.html'

Comment: my error Is page not found, when I am not logged in so it dosen't redirect correctly

Comment: also tried this: @login_required
def Assignments(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('%s?next=%s' % ('utility-login.html', request.path))
    return render(request, 'nav-side-team.html')

Answer (score 0):

studyplans is missing the decorator **login_required**.

According to the docs, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator, the easiest way should be

```
@login_required
def studyplans(request):
  return render(request, 'allStudyplans.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it – probably equivalent to the above – is with "mixins":

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin

class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
   ...
```

Notice that "mixin" class names should occur first in the list, before `View`.

(Notice that I also show that there's a "permission-required mixin.")

I guess it just comes down to personal preference, and consistency with the existing source-code of the application.